# axios request return undefined in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

When I try to make axios request in useEffect hook, it returns undefined,
but I find it's successful when viewing in Network request in Inspect Mode

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com`
});
```

PostService.js

```
import instance from "./api";

export default {
  getPost: () => {
    instance({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/posts"
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import PostService from "./PostService";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await PostService.getPost();
      console.log(response); //return undefined
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
   ...
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-leftpad-cz12i?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in your `PostService`:

```js
import instance from "./api";

export default {
  getPost: () => {
    return instance({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/posts"
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  }
};
```

Without the `return`, `PostService` is calling the api and fetching the data, but it's not sending anything back to your `fetchData` function calling it.